# react native set app icon badge number

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native, push-notification

I set the badge number on my IOS app icon through PushNotificationIOS API. However, I don't see the number above the icon at all. There are no errors.

```
componentDidMount() {
    //PushNotificationIOS.requestPermissions(['badge','alert','sound']);
    PushNotificationIOS.setApplicationIconBadgeNumber(10);
    PushNotificationIOS.getApplicationIconBadgeNumber((res)=>{
        console.log(res) //returns 10
    });
}
```

Comment: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/pushnotificationios.html